# Can this SQLite3 Query that summarises survey data be improved?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following table schema which describes respondents' responsest to a survey consisting of questions (Q1, Q2..Qn) each having multiple-choice answers (Q1a1, Q1a2, Q2a1...):

```
respondent | group | Q1   | Q2   | ... Qn
  fred     |  xyz  | Q1a1 | Q2a3 | ...
   joe     |  xyz  | Q1a2 | q2a1 | ...
  bill     |  abc  | Q1a1 | Q2a4 | ...
```

In a simple question, Q1a1 might be "Yes" and Q1a2 might be "No" but consider the answers to be any simple text strings that are known by their presence in the source data (the potential for possible but unused answers can be ignored).

Each row represents a unique respondent and there are many respondents in each group. Each respondent answers each question giving one of the valid answers for each question.

I want to tabulate, per group, how many (portentially none) of each answer there are for each question: I want to produce:

```
group | Q1_a1 | Q1_a2 | Q1_a3 | Q2_a1 | Q2_a2 | Q3_a1 | ...
 xyz  |  32   |  12   |   9   |  11   |   23  |   2   | ...
 abc  |  27   |   6   |       |  18   |   12  |  26   | ...
```

**I want to do this in sqlite3** and I have a query that I think works but I also think it is unwieldy and doesn't scale well for a large number of questions:

```
WITH Q1YES AS (SELECT RespondentGroup, COUNT(*) AS yes FROM DATA
                 WHERE Q1 = 'Yes'
                 GROUP BY RespondentGroup),
     Q1NO   AS (SELECT RespondentGroup, COUNT(*) AS no FROM DATA
                 WHERE Q1 = 'No'
                 GROUP BY RespondentGroup),

     Q2YES  AS (SELECT RespondentGroup, COUNT(*) AS yes FROM DATA
                 WHERE Q2 = 'Yes'
                 GROUP BY RespondentGroup),
     Q2NO   AS (SELECT RespondentGroup, COUNT(*) AS no FROM DATA
                 WHERE Q2 = 'No'
                 GROUP BY RespondentGroup),
     Q2PART AS (SELECT RespondentGroup, COUNT(*) AS part FROM DATA
                 WHERE Q2 = 'Part'
                 GROUP BY RespondentGroup)                                                                                                                    

SELECT DISTINCT DATA.RespondentGroup as RespondentGroup,
        Q1YES.yes as "Q1 Yes", Q1NO.no as "Q1 No",
        Q2YES.yes as "Q2 Yes", Q2NO.no as "Q2 No", Q2PART.part as "Q2 Part"

  FROM DATA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Q1YES  on Q1YES.RespondentGroup   = DATA.RespondentGroup
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Q1NO   on Q1NO.RespondentGroup    = DATA.RespondentGroup

  LEFT OUTER JOIN Q2YES  on Q2YES.RespondentGroup   = DATA.RespondentGroup
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Q2NO   on Q2NO.RespondentGroup    = DATA.RespondentGroup
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Q2PART on Q2PART.RespondentGroup  = DATA.RespondentGroup

ORDER BY RespondentGroup;
```

**Can this query be improved (answers must work in SQLite3) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
select DATA.Respondentgroup as RespondentGroup
  , sum( case Q1 when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end  ) as Q1Yes
  , sum( case Q1 when 'No' then 1 else 0 end  ) as Q1No
  , sum( case Q2 when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end  ) as Q2Yes
  , sum( case Q2 when 'No' then 1 else 0 end  ) as Q2No
  , sum( case Q2 when 'Part' then 1 else 0 end  ) as Q2Part

From DATA
group by DATA.Respondentgroup
order by 1
```

Comment: In SQLite, boolean expressions return 0/1, so this can be simplified with `sum(Q1 = 'Yes')` etc.